# How to be ensure that function is executed to delegate process further?

Tags: javascript

I have some functions in JS, that should be executed sequenced. One of them can return value (sync), others no, or can return Observable result (async).

So, how to be ensure that any function is executed and pass delegate execution further to next function?

Certainly, I can use callback for each function or wrap each other to Promise.

As instance:

```
 function one() {
     return 1;
 }

 function two(r1) {
     return 2;
 }

 function three(r2): void {

 }

 function fourObs(r3): Observable<any> {
     return new Observable();
 }
```

So, I need the following calls stack:

```
r1 = one();

if (r1) {
    r2 = two(r1);

    if (r2) {
        r3 = three(r2);

        if (r3) {
            fourObs(r3).subscribe({(data) => console.log(data); });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not make them resolve promises and chain the promises (async/await)?

Comment: Cause some functions can be sync some not, and how to wrap them to promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function which calls a given functions recursively one by one like so:

```js
// Helper fn
const logArg = val => console.log(`Previous value ${val}`);
const logName = fn => console.log(`Fn ${fn.name.replace('bound ', '')} called`);

// Fn a returns Boolean
const a = () => true;
// Fn b returns Void (undefined)
const b = previousResult => { logArg(previousResult); };
// Fn c returns Promise<Number>
const c = previousResult => new Promise(resolve => {
  logArg(previousResult);
  resolve(10);
});
// Fn d returns String - but is called last so the result isn't passed anywhere
const d = previousResult => {
  logArg(previousResult);
  return '10';
};

function runInSequence (...fns) {
  const fn = fns[0];
  const result = fn();
  
  logName(fn);
  
  if (fns.length === 1) {
    return;
  } else if (result instanceof Promise) {
    // If function returns a Promise, wait for it to be resolved
    result.then(value => runInSequence(
      fns[1].bind(null, value),
      ...fns.slice(2),
    ));
  } else {
    // Otherwise just continue
    runInSequence(
      fns[1].bind(null, result),
      ...fns.slice(2),
    );
  }
}

runInSequence(
  a,
  b,
  c,
  d,
);
```

Comment: How to pass result c to d?

Comment: Why you bind null to `d` function? `d.bind(null, 10)`, does it mean the same? `d(null, 10)`?

Comment: No, check the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind. When you bind the function you can specify its parameters and call it later with just `fn()`.

Comment: Problem is that I need pass result to the next method, not outside

Comment: Can I bind like: `result.then(() => runInSequence(...fns.slice(1).bind(result)));`

Comment: This is that it does though. Fn A returns `true` and Fn B has `true` as an argument, same way Fn B returns `undefined` (=void) and Fn C has `undefined` as an argument, Fn C returns `10` and Fn D has `10` as an argument